# Merging 'apt-get search' and 'apt-get policy'

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

While trying to combine output of `apt-get search` and `apt-get policy`, I have created this following script.

```
apt-cache search zsh | \
tee file1 | awk '{ print $1 }' | \
while read file; do apt-cache policy $file | awk 'FNR==2{print $0}' >> file2; done; \
paste file1 file2 | cat
```

It seems to be logically correct to me but the output is wrong. I begin to test outputs command by command and saw that doing `wc` of file `file2` returns `1353 lines`

```
apt-cache search zsh | \
tee file1 | awk '{ print $1 }' | \
while read file; do apt-cache policy $file | awk 'FNR==2{print $0}' >> file2; done; \
cat file2 | wc -l
```

but `wc` just after the first line returns `123 lines`

```
apt-cache search bash | wc -l
```

So `while` loop was never fetched `1353 lines` of output, yet it processes that.

I was expecting the output like

```
zgen - Lightweight plugin manager for ZSH inspired by Antigen    Installed: (none)
zplug - next-generation plugin manager for zsh                   Installed: (none)
zsh - shell with lots of features                                Installed: <version>
.
.
.
```

Is the logic of my script wrong?

Where am I making the mistake here?

**Edit: The script given by Steeldriver in the comments below is working fine but could someone please explain what's wrong with the above script**

Comment: Are you remembering to truncate or remove `file2` between runs? Regardless, you can do the whole thing with a single `read` and a single `awk` I think e.g. `apt-cache search zsh | while read -r pkg desc; do apt-cache policy "$pkg" | awk -v pkg="$pkg" -v desc="$desc" 'NR==2 {print pkg, desc, $0}'; done`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, your script runs exactly how I wanted, but I am still not able to understand what problem is there with my scirpt. Why would I need to truncate `file2` when I am already passing truncated content of `apt-cache search` to the while loop using `awk '{ print $1 }'` command in the second pipe

Comment: You are *appending* to `file2` eac time you run your code; assuming that you've tested it a few times then `file2` will contain the results of all the previous runs unless you truncate it (`> file2`) or remove it (`rm file2`) between runs

Comment: @steeldriver Got it, thank you so much for helping.... <3 <3

Comment: @steeldriver Please post that as an answer so the OP can accept.